# Tablesorter: How to continue zebra into the footer

Tags: jquery, html

I've got a hard coded HTML table with our little phone list and I've got the empty stations in a footer so they don't get sorted by tablesorter.  However, this also excludes them from being zebra striped by tablesorter as well.  Is there a way to make tablesorter see the footer for zebra purposes but not for sorting?  Or should I just use jQuery to do the zebra striping and not use tablesorter's widget?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the solution ended up being to continue to use tablesorter for both the sorting and zebra, but also just independently zebra stripe the footer using jQuery by adding something like `$("#tableid tr:odd").addClass("odd");` in the same ready function.  Since this is exactly what the zebra widget does to begin with, the results come out exactly the same, but it now extends to the footer as well.  The resulting table will be appropriately zebra striped, but the rows we want fixed to the bottom stay put.